# Extracting the file name from the variable dynamically

Tags: java, file

I have a query a method in which the parameter is coming as a file name that upon debugging I have analyzed, as shown below:

```
private processfile ( string filePath)

{

}
```

Now this file path can be like:

```
C:\abc\file1.txt
or 
C:\abc\def\file1.txt
or 
C:\ghj\ytr\wer\file1.txt
```

Now my query is that I have to extract the file name only and have to store in a string parameter. So I have to store the `file1.txt` in a string, let say in a string parameter `s` , so finally `s` will be stored as

```
String s = file1.txt
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

This should do the trick

```
String s = new File(filepath).getName()
```

although I would rename filepath to filePath.

You can find `File#getName()` documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `indexOf` and `substring` for this case:

```
String s = filepath.substring(filepath.lastIndexOf(File.separator)+1);
```

`File.getName` also takes similar approach, see source below:

```
public String getName() {
    int index = path.lastIndexOf(separatorChar);
    if (index < prefixLength) return path.substring(prefixLength);
    return path.substring(index + 1);
    }
```